# Can I use math functions in PIC16F877A code?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, programming

Can I use exponential (exp) math function in PIC16F877A code? For example like this:

```
double a,ans;
a=5.7;
ans=exp(0.5);
```

Comment: I assume you're working in C? What compiler do you use?

Comment: The question relates to the compiler and not to the microcontroller used per se. ANY mc can implement any function  that is implemented in a modern language subject only to memory constraints. Whether it is sensible to do so, or possible with a given language are other issues and what you need to ask about to get a good answer. (ie YES you can do what you ask - but whether a given tool does it and whether it is a good idea are unknowable without more information.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you find yourself in need of floating point math and you are using an 8-bit microcontroller with an architecture from the seventies, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PIC16F877A is an 8-bit microcontroller without a floating point unit (FPU). Therefore, any floating point math must be done by software emulation. Typically, this is handled through a compiler library, so it is highly dependent on which compiler you are using, which you did not specify. See if your compiler has a header file such as math.h, etc. Your compiler documentation will specify what file(s) need to be included, which functions are available, how much program/data memory and processor cycles each function will require.

Also, note that because your microcontroller can only operate on 8-bit data words, operations with ANSI C compliant "doubles", which are at least 64-bits will be extremely slow. Typically for embedded operations it is best to use type "float" if 32-bits is enough precision for your application. It will still be slow, but less extremely slow (some compiler do not even support double, and will automatically assume use of type float).

Answer (score 3):

The question relates to the compiler and not to the microcontroller used per se.
ANY microcontroller can implement any function  that is implemented in a modern language, subject only to memory constraints. Whether it is sensible to do so, or possible with a given language are other issues and what you need to ask about to get a good answer.

That is:
YES you can do what you ask -
BUT whether a given tool does it and whether it is a good idea are unknowable without more information.